# timeupdate event function doesn't update variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I want to make video loop. I have two time inputs #from and #to. 
When I run script first time, it works but if I change values in inputs, timeupdate event doesn't update variables.

But it works if I change input value and enter less number then previous. 
can you tell me please what's wrong with this code, or is there any other way?

I'm sorry, I don't speak english well.

P.S. chrome debugger shows correct values.

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
    var from, to;
    switch (request.todo) {
        case 'loopVideo':
        from = request.from.split(':');
        from = +from[0] * 60 + +from[1];

        to = request.to.split(':');
        to = +to[0] * 60 + +to[1];
        console.log(from, to);
        console.log(request.from, request.to);
        $('video').get(0).addEventListener('timeupdate', () => {
            if ($('video').get(0).currentTime >= to) {
                $('video').get(0).currentTime = from;
                console.log(from, to);
                console.log(request.from, request.to);
            }
        });
    break;
    }
});
```

Comment: This is something you need to debug. Use devtools to set a breakpoint in the code and when it triggers on a message, inspect the variables, the elements, step through the code and so on. BTW you're adding a new timeupdate listener on each message without disconnecting the old one which is also active.

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks, this is the first time I'm trying to create chrome extension.